# Excel copy contents from multiple cells adding quotations

Tags: excel, ms-office, formula

I'm trying to combine contents from multiple cells in excel.  Here is an example of what i'm wanting to do:

(Cell1): John Doe

(Cell2):  5950

(Cell3):  Autofill with **"John Doe" XXXXXX5950**

I know i can combine the cells using the formula =&[Cell1]&" XXXXXX"&[Cell2]

But I want it to put the " " on each side of the name, but the code won't except it since part of using the formula is using the " symbol.  Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two double-quotes inside a string to put a double-quote:

```
=""""&[Cell1]&""" XXXXXX"&[Cell2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the `"` character in VBA by using double quotes.

```
Range("A1").Formula = """" & Range("B1").Value & """ XXXXXX" & Range("C1").Value
```

Or you can also use ASCII character 34 as well.

```
Range("A1").Formula = Chr(34) & Range("B1").Value & Chr(34) & " XXXXX" & Range("C2").Value
```